# Android - Proguard obfuscate not able to find android classes

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I am unable to run obfuscate on my android project. I keep getting a 100 errors each saying the similar thing -

```
[javac]     /MyPath/LocationReceiver.java:34: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class Intent
[javac] location: class com.myPath.LocationReceiver
[javac]     public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
```

Where would I need to look? My build.xml file has all the correct android paths specified.

My build file -

```
<property name="src.dir"     value="src/com"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/> 
<property name="input.jar.file" value="${build.dir}/temp.jar"/>
<property name="obfuscated_sdk.jar.file" value="${build.dir}/MyName.jar"/>
<property name="proguard-home" value="/MyPath/proguard4.6" />
<property name="android-home" value="/MyPath/android-sdk" />
<property name="android-version" value="8" />
<property name="android-platform-specific" value="${android-home}/platforms/android-${android-version}" />
<property name="android-jar" value="${android-platform-specific}/android.jar" />

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="build-sdk" depends="clean" description="compiles the sdk java files"> 
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}"
             destdir="${classes.dir}"
             source="1.6"  
                 debuglevel="lines">
            <classpath>
                <path>
                    <pathelement location="${android-jar}" /> 
                </path>
            </classpath>
    </javac>
</target> 

<target name="create.input.jar" depends="build-sdk"> 
    <jar destfile="${input.jar.file}" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="MyName" value="v1.0"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target> 

<target name="Obfuscate" depends="create.input.jar" description="shrink compiled classes">
    <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties" classpath="/MyPath/proguard4.6/lib/proguard.jar" />
    <proguard>
        -libraryjars "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar"
        -libraryjars "/MyPath/android-sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar" 
        -injars      ${input.jar.file}
        -outjars     ${obfuscated_sdk.jar.file}  

</proguard>
    <delete file="${input.jar.file}"/>
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Sure looks like a classpath problem. Are you doing this from within Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I am. I also get package android.app does not exist and package android.content does not exist errors if that helps

Comment: Does this happen with every build, or just when exporting a signed .apk file?

Comment: I am just trying to run it on my source code. Tried it only with one project yet.

Comment: hah. now you know what the customer who uses your obfuscated software feels like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a classpath problem. It probably doesn't have anything to do with ProGuard, since the Android build system only invokes that when exporting a signed .apk file. Also, I believe that Eclipse uses its own build system and does not rely on build.xml.

Things to try:

1. Make sure that you created your project as an Android project. If not, start over again.
2. Right click on the project name in the package explorer and select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
3. Open the project properties, select Android and make sure you have a Project Build Target selected. Then select Java Build Path, and make sure that an Android library shows up in the Libraries pane.

Comment: My project builds and runs fine. Its just when I try to run the Obfuscate that I get the errors.

Comment: I run the build.xml with an ant script. I have added the file in my question above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suggest that you abandon using your own script. Instead, just export a signed .apk file from within Eclipse. It not only compiles and signs, it runs zipalign and then ProGuard (using the contents of proguard.cfg in the project directory to control obfuscation).

Comment: I kind of have to run my own script because I am essentially creating an sdk, which is just a bunch of java files (not an android project) using the android sdk jar. Is there a simpler way to proguard such files?

Comment: The error messages look like they are coming from the javac task, not the proguard task. Do you get the same behavior with `make build-sdk`? Also, try using `classpath=${android-jar}` as an attribute to the javac task, instead of using a nested `classpath` element.

Comment: One other thought -- try generating an android project from the command line (using the `android create project` command as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html). If the makefile that it generates works, then comparing it with the one you are using might bring into focus what's going wrong.